# magento stock sql

Tags: sql, magento, stock

```
SELECT sku, qty FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` i join `catalog_product_entity` e on i.product_id = e.entity_id where i.qty <= 100 and i.is_in_stock
```

I want a query which get the product `sku`, `supplier_barcode`, 
`supplier_sku` where stock less then 100.
`supplier_barcode`, `supplier_sku` are custom attribute.

above query just giving `sku`,`qty` `where qty <=100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find out what table and `attribute_id` you need.

Run this query to find out:

```
SELECT t1.attribute_id, t1.attribute_code, t1.backend_type
FROM eav_entity_type AS t0
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_type_id = t1.entity_type_id)
WHERE (t0.entity_model = 'catalog/product')
```

That'll give you something like this:

```
attribute_id | attribute_code      | backend_type
------------ | ------------------- | ------------
230          | brand               | varchar     
228          | cardboard_height_cm | varchar     
227          | cardboard_width_cm  | varchar     
108          | category_ids        | static      
92           | color               | int         
79           | cost                | decimal
```

Then you can go and build queries like this:

```
SELECT t1.entity_id, t1.attribute_id, t1.entity_type_id, t1.store_id, t1.value, t1.value_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS t1
  ON (((t1.attribute_id = 71) AND (t1.store_id = 0)) AND (t1.entity_id = t0.entity_id))
WHERE (t0.sku IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY t0.sku
```

Then you can join the up as you need.

---

Here's an example of the kind of query you need with the joins:

```
SELECT t0.sku, t1.qty, t2.value, t3.value AS value1
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.product_id)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t4.entity_id, t4.value
  FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS t4
  WHERE ((t4.attribute_id = 71) AND (t4.store_id = 0))
  ) AS t2
  ON (t0.entity_id = t2.entity_id)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t5.entity_id, t5.value
  FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS t5
  WHERE ((t5.attribute_id = 207) AND (t5.store_id = 0))
  ) AS t3
  ON (t0.entity_id = t3.entity_id)
WHERE ((t0.sku IS NOT NULL) AND (t1.qty <= 100))
```

Comment: how can i get the value of 
221  supplier_barcode  varchar
222  supplier_sku          varchar
if sku from cataloginventory_stock_item qty <= 100

Comment: @SyedHusaain - You'd do a couple of joins Are you not familiar with building SQL queries?

Comment: not good in sql, i want to pick sku and qty where qty <=10, by this query SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` i 
join `catalog_product_entity` e 
on i.product_id = e.entity_id 
where i.qty <= 10 and i.is_in_stock, i also want to pick supp barcode and supp sku by attribute code.

Comment: @SyedHusaain - I understand what you want to do. I wanted to know if you're able to build the query from what I've given you.

Comment: @SyedHusaain - I've added a join example.

Comment: this query work perfect, this sql query is an advance level or beginning level

Comment: @SyedHusaain - The query was generated from C# code in LINQPad. I don't know if it is advanced or basic.

Comment: it works if backend_type is varchar, i have attribute name "brand", attribute is dropdown, backend_type int. any idea how to get its value.

Comment: @SyedHusaain - Try changing `catalog_product_entity_varchar` to `catalog_product_entity_int`.

Comment: @SyedHusaain - What do you mean? The value from `catalog_product_entity_int` is a number.

Comment: Name        brand
product-1      634
product-2      640
product-3      633

Comment: @SyedHusaain - That doesn't explain what you mean.

Comment: i need text data or varchar catalog_product_entity_varchar table, has varchar data and  catalog_product_entity_int has type int

Comment: @SyedHusaain - I don't know how you're trying to consume the data. There must be a very simple conversion available to you?

Comment: INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t7.entity_id, t7.value
  FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS t7
  WHERE ((t7.attribute_id = ???) AND (t7.store_id = 0))
  ) AS t7
  ON (t0.entity_id = t7.entity_id) , if you run this what will be answer

Comment: @SyedHusaain - I don't know what you asking me?

Comment: INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t7.entity_id, t7.value
  FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS t7
  WHERE ((t7.attribute_id = 238) AND (t7.store_id = 0))
  ) AS t7
  ON (t0.entity_id = t7.entity_id)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        I want brand name,  right now this line just print brand numbers

Comment: @SyedHusaain - There must be a lookup for the brand from the number. You need to figure that out.

Comment: @SyedHusaain - No. It's like me asking you where I left my car keys. I have no idea how your Magento looks up brand names from an id. You need to find that.

Comment: it always on my right pocket of jeans, i will find out soon thx